# Clojure: Idiomatic way to wrap each element in collection

Tags: collections, clojure

If I have a collection of a particular shape:

```
["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"]  ;; vector of strings
```

and I want to transform it by wrapping each element:

```
[{:name "Alpha"}, {:name "Beta"}, {:name "Gamma"}]
```

Is there a better way to express that than this rather kludgy `map`?

```
(map #(identity {:name %}) coll)
```

Comment: I quite like `#(-> {:name %})`, short and easy to read, you can also use `do` instead of the arrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use `fn`:

```
(map (fn [v] {:name v}) coll)
```

if you want to use the anonymous function syntax you can use `array-map` to construct the map:

```
(map #(array-map :name %) coll)
```

Comment: `hash-map` works too. I just tracked down some advice about when you might want one v.s. the other (at least how Clojure libraries seem to handle it). http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/array-map#example-57392e25e4b071da7d6cfd0c

Answer (score 4):

If you don't like `map` with `(fn [v] {:name v})` you can use `for`:

```
(for [v coll] {:name v})
;; => ({:name "Alpha"} {:name "Beta"} {:name "Gamma"})
```

Comment: Thanks. Lee's `map` highlights the underlying operation being performed, so I think that's a better choice.